# Generic method to return instance of child class in List of parent classes

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something but I don't know how to call/name this and I can't find anything usefull on Google. I have base class

```
public class Parent{/*some code here*/}
```

and child classes

```
public class Child1:Parent{/*more code*/}
public class Child2:Parent{/*expended behaviour*/}
```

If I create

```
List<Parent> children = new List<Parent>();
```

I can happily put all children in that list but I have trouble writing generic method for retrieving them. Something like this:

```
public T GetChild<T>()
{
    var child = children.Find(c => c.GetType() == typeof(T));
    if (child == null)
        return default(T);
    return child;
}
```

Compiler complains at last line and if I try to cast `child` to `T` explicitely, it complains some more. What shall I do, please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method to get all instances of specific class. `children.OfType<T>();` Then if you need a single instance you can use [`First`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiexIa0sKPNAhVDD8AKHXJbDicQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb291976(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGyocV6T9pbROtBArRfyDa5B9ZZAA&sig2=hhRlAF2jLYih1SyYMU8D5A&bvm=bv.124272578,d.ZGg&cad=rja) or [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj4mMHOsaPNAhVDDcAKHSKgBhgQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFgQyK5Xg2VyTpg4dBSxbrgrD5pcA&sig2=LUp9FhX6t-ay5zw2dDx7vg&bvm=bv.124272578,d.ZGg&cad=rja) method.

```
    public T GetChild<T>() 
    {
        var child = children.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (child == null)
            return default(T);
        return child;
    }
```

Or just

```
public T GetChild<T>() 
{
    return children.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: But do you need 2nd and 3rd line? FirstOrDefault returns null if nothing is found and I expect to return null from my method if nothing is found too.

Comment: @DreadBoy Yes, you can remove this lines, if you want to return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of parent in front of multiple children where you need to find out their types using "is" keyword. Something like:

if(child is Child1) return Child1;
else return Child2;

Comment: That would defeat purpose of generic function, wouldn't it? Imagine I have 10 child classes, I would need 10 if clauses. Or imagine I add another child later on and forget about this line. Generic function I want to write is going to do its job, no matter how many new child classes I add.